# Json Data not loading in jqGrid with spring 3 mvc

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

On click of a button I am trying to load the jqgrid with json datadtype.
I tried many ways to load data but it gets fails and displays empty grid.
Please advise wht I am missing here.

My Grid

```
$("#bedata").click(function(){
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'/mso/interop/interopcompanycfg/getDSAccounts?companyId=${interopcompcfg.company.id}',
      datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Id','DTCCID','COMPANYID','DTCCACCOUNTID'],         
        colModel:[
         {name:'ID',index:'id', sortable:true, align:'center',width:90},
         {name:'DTCCID',index:'dsId', sortable:true, align:'center',width:90},
         {name:'COMPANYID',index:'companyId',sortable:true, align:'center', width:120},
         {name:'DTCCACCOUNTID',index:'dsLegalEntityId', sortable:true, align:'center',width:130}      
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'dsId',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"DS ACCOUNTS",
        jsonReader: {
      repeatitems : false,    
      root:"rows",
      cell: "",
      id: "0"
      } 
    });
  jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
 });


spring requestmapping
@RequestMapping(value="/getDSAccounts",method= RequestMethod.GET) 
 public @ResponseBody  List<Vector<String>> getDSAccountsJSON(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
  try{

   UsersJsonDTO usersJsonDTO = new UsersJsonDTO(); 
      usersJsonDTO.setPage("1");   
   usersJsonDTO.setRecords("8");     
   usersJsonDTO.setTotal("20");

   Company cmp=(Company) request.getSession().getAttribute("company"); 
   List<DSAccounts> message = interopService.getDSAccounts(cmp);  

   httpResponse.setContentType("text/javascript");
   int i=0;
   List<DTCCAccounts> rowJsonList = new ArrayList<DTCCAccounts>();   
    for (DSAccounts dsAccountDTO:message)
    {   
    DTCCAccounts rowJson = new DTCCAccounts();       
    rowJson.setId(String.valueOf(i+1));
    rowJson.setDsId(String.valueOf(dsAccountDTO.getDsId()));
    rowJson.setCompanyId(String.valueOf(dsAccountDTO.getCompany().getId()));
    rowJson.setDsLegalEntityId(dsAccountDTO.getDsLegalEntityId());
    rowJsonList.add(rowJson);
    } 

   usersJsonDTO.setRows(rowJsonList);
      return usersJsonDTO;
```

Comment: Could you post your JSON so we can validate it? You can also validate it yourself using http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: I verified in jsonlimt.com and the Json is a valid one. {
   "page": "1",
   "records": "8",
   "rows":    [
            {
         "companyId": "1661",
         "dsId": "72",
         "dsLegalEntityId": "SELLSIDE01",
         "id": "1"
      },       
            {
         "companyId": "1661",
         "dsId": "74",
         "dsLegalEntityId": "SELLSIDE03",
         "id": "1"
      }
          ],
   "total": "20"
}

Comment: I suspect that the jsonmapping in colModel is causing the problem..but no where any documentation or examples available. a hint or supporting link would be great help

Answer (score 0):

If the your JSON data contain elements like

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "records": "8",
    "rows": [
        {
            "companyId": "1661",
            "dsId": "72",
            "dsLegalEntityId": "SELLSIDE01",
            "id": "1" 
        },
        {
            "companyId": "1661",
            "dsId": "74",
            "dsLegalEntityId": "SELLSIDE03",
            "id": "1" 
        } 
    ],
    "total": "20" 
}
```

You should change the `name` property of all columns to the values which you currently use for `index` and the grid will be filled with the data.

One more problem exist in your data: you have **two elements with the same id**. So if you would be select the second row, the first one will be selected. So you should choose "dsId" as the id or produce the data having unique ids.

**UPDATED:** [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sabari0.htm) is the same code where only the names are fixed and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sabari.htm) is the same grid where ids are also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting all the properties of your jsonReader. Like this

```
jsonReader : {
      root: "rows",
      page: "page",
      total: "total",
      records: "records",
      repeatitems: false,
      cell: "cell",
      id: "id"
}
```

What you have is this:

```
jsonReader: {
  repeatitems : false,    
  root:"rows",
  cell: "",
  id: "0"
}
```

Why is the id set to **0**? How would the jqGrid know what the id is from your JSON data? Also, why have you removed the **total**, **page**, **cell** properties?

The JSON format I returned from my Spring MVC 3 application is exactly the following:

```
{
"total":"10",
"page":"1",
"records":"3",
"rows":[{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"},
    {"id":2,"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Adams"},
    {"id":3,"firstName":"Jeff","lastName":"Mayer"}]
```

}

Also, I notice you did the following:

```
 httpResponse.setContentType("text/javascript");
```

I didn't have to do that in my Spring 3 MVC. Check this tutorial I wrote at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html

Comment: Sorry, but one need include only the properies of `jsonReador` which are **different from default settings**. In the jqGrid documentation http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data are also described what mean `id:"0"`. It is correct setting. One can achive the same results including `key:true` in the ID column definition. The tutorial which you wrote seems interesting, but jqGrid allows *different ways of serializations of the data*. One need only use the corresponding `jsonReader` and sometime also using of additional `jsonmap` option.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried right now. I removed all the properties. It turns out you just need the repeatitems: false property inside the jsonReader. It turns out jqGrid has an internal field name conventions. If your JSON response is not using 'rows' as the root name, then you will have to explicitly declare the root property.

Comment: @Oleg, you're right. It's not needed if you're following the jqGrid naming convention. In the case of Sabari (the person who asked), his JSON seems acceptable. Maybe the problem is with his Spring. I suspect that contentType.

Comment: No, in the case it's only the names of columns which I described in my answer. After the changes of names the data will be displayed: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sabari0.htm. Next small problem is double ids. After the changes the grid will be displaced correctly http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sabari.htm

Comment: @Oleg, verified. I played with my jqGrid-Spring 3 app. I set the contentType like how Sabari did it. It didn't mess the loading of data. Then I tried changing the case of colModel names to all UPPER CASE and it messed up the loading of data. In other words, the colModel names must exactly match the JSON names in your JSON data, including the case.